# Using "this" in Java vs Short Parameter Names

Tags: java, parameters, this

Which do you prefer and why?

```
public void setPresenter(Presenter presenter) {
    this.presenter = presenter;
}

public void setPresenter(Presenter p) {
    presenter = p;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I prefer the `this`-notation, at least in constructors, and compound setter methods, where you have multiple arguments.

- You don't have to come up with two variable names for each field.
- It is clear from the "outside", what the argument represents.
- It is really a standard approach.

In the particular case of a setter, I don't really have an opinion, since the method name is explanatory enough, and the implementation is a single assignment.

Comment: +1: Your first two reasons are good ones. I'm less sure about the last one.

Comment: Right, I agree. I actually had constructors in mind when writing the last one.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer `this` - this class illustrates why

```
class foo {

    int value;
    int otherValue;

    void setValue(int i) {
        value = i;
    }

    void setOtherValue(int i) {
        otherValue = i;
    }

    // uhh what? 
    void setBoth(int i, int j) {
        // which one should be first? oh, you guessed and got it wrong? tooooo bad!

    }


}
```

Comment: This is a terrible and utterly contrived example.

Comment: I'm not too sure what the issue is here, but I'm guessing the ambiguity in setBoth is that both setValue and setOtherValue are using the parameter i and it's confusing which should be called to set i in setBoth?

Comment: @Aram basically. @Monkey Let's say you were in your IDE and you do `myFoo.setBoth(` and it pops up `i` and `j` for names. It really isn't as apparent as if it had said `value` and `otherValue`.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense now. If anything I've been taught to use longer names if it means adding more information. That said, if the method name is explanatory enough, it should't be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

We use full words for instance variables and TLAs for methods, so ours would have:

```
public void setPresenter(Presenter prs) {
    presenter=prs;
    }
```

That allows reasonably clear names, avoids misassignment bugs caused by an omitted `this` and clearly distinguishes long-term/wide-scope identifiers from short-term/narrow-scope ones.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer not to use `this` since (accidentially) leaving it out (while mostly using it) could lead to shadowing bugs on longer methods.

However, you should use a sensible name for the parameters.
That's why I prefer to use prefixes for parameters and local variables:

```
public void setPresenter(Presenter pPresenter) {
    presenter = pPresenter;   //pXxxx stands for 'parameter'
    Presenter tPresenter = pPresenter;  //tXxxx stands for 'temporary' or local
}
```

Comment: do you prefix booleans with `b` and member variables with `m_` as well? ;-)

Comment: No, I don't use hungarian notation and no prefixes for members. :) As said, this makes it easier to prevent shadowing bugs and wee whether you are working with a parameter, local variable or member - espcially in longer methods.

Comment: This is similar to Software Monkey's suggestion which is closer to the second method I posted. I think the crux of the matter is to ensure local scope variables are separate from member variables. I tend to overuse "this" to make this explicit, but there are cases where it becomes superfluous - like with short setters.

Comment: -1 for polluting the public doc realm _and_ the internal code sphere, so hurting both users of the api and maintainers. IDEs typically warn against most types of mis/not assignments. If any method is so long you forget which is what - refactor ;-)

Comment: How does that pollute the doc realm and hurt maintainers more than using other conventions? At least you know how the variable is intended to use. If you don't use any prefixes you're hurting the maintainers and possibly users of the api more in that you don't support when they just have the code.